# Insert timediff result in a table

Tags: mysql

Inserting timedifference into table

i have tried this query

```
insert into `hours` (id,totalhours)
values (NULL, timediff('2012/10/25 06:06:06','2012/10/25 08:06:06'));
```

but i´m not sure what kind of fields needs to be totalhours,
 i tried with date,datetime,time but the result is null for totalhours

Answer (score 1):

You can store calculated hours in `int` ,`double` or `varchar` type fields depends on format in which you want to store.

date, datetime,time will accept values in their predefined format.

Illegal `DATE`, `DATETIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` `TIME` values are converted to the “zero” value of the 
appropriate type (`'0000-00-00' or '0000-00-00 00:00:00' or 00:00:00` respectively).

Answer (score 0):

the date format mysql follow is with `-` not with `/` so go with

insert into hours (id,totalhours) values (NULL, TIMEDIFF('2012-10-25 06:06:06','2012-10-25 08:06:06'));

i hope this will help you. or else follow [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the time difference in hours

use

```
insert into `hours` (id,totalhours)
VALUES (NULL,HOUR(TIMEDIFF('2012-10-25 06:06:06','2012-10-25 08:06:06')))
```